# php empty multidimensional array doesnt work! error: Undefined offset 0

Tags: php, arrays

I have table in html code and I want put the table data in multdemensional array. and I have this error:

Undefined offset 0 ...

HTML code:

```
<td><input type="text" name="col[][]"  /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="col[][]"  /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="col[][]"  /></td>
```

PHP code:

```
 for ($k=0; $k<=2; $k++){ 

        for ($l=0; $l<=6; $l++){ //column
            echo $col[$k][$l];
        }
    }
```

Comment: post the *relevant* part of the code... html & php... and try to print_r/var_dump $_POST if its post data

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)